# Need remove values after comma in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Value is stored as string, need to remove the value after comma.

Example- str_CurrentValue = "120.0", "0.0"

Comment: I don't see any VB code in your question. Please post code that actually compiles. `"120.0", "0.0"` is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Echoing the sentiments of @41686d6564 that you really need to put more clarity to your question, I'll work on the assumption that if you did a `Console.WriteLine(str_CurrentValue)` you would see `"120.0", "0.0"` emitted in the console, you can remove everything after the first comma in a string with:

```
str_CurrentValue.Remove()
```

You should ensure that the string does contain a comma first though..

```
Dim idx = str_CurrentValue.IndexOf(","c)
If idx > -1 Then someVariable = str_CurrentValue.Remove(idx)
```

Split is expensive, if you're only going to throw most of it away, but this also does what you seek, and doesn't crash if no commas are present in the string:

```
str_CurrentValue.Split(","c)(0)
```